# Why do I get a 'function is undefined' even though I added the function to the constructor's prototype?

Tags: javascript

Running the code below:

```
console.clear();

var array = [ 'Apples', 'Oranges', , 'Pear', ];

array.first = function()
{
  var len = this.length;

  if (len === 0) throw new Error("Array empty");

  return array[0];
}

Array.prototype.last = function()
{
  var len = this.length;
  if (len === 0) throw new Error("Empty array");
  return array[len - 1];
}


console.log("========================")
for(prop in array)
  console.log(prop + " = " + array[prop].toString());

console.log("========================")

try
  {
    var first = array.first();
    console.log("first = " + first.toString());
  }
catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e.message);
  }

try
  {
    var last = array.last();
    console.log("last  = " + last.toString());
  }
catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e.message);
  }


console.log("========================")
var newArray = [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ];

for(prop in newArray)
  console.log(prop + " = " + newArray[prop].toString());

console.log("========================")

try
  {
    var first = newArray.first();
    console.log("first = " + first.toString());
  }
catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e.message);
  }

try
  {
    var last = newArray.last();
    console.log("last  = " + last.toString());
  }
catch(e)
  {
    console.log(e.message);
  }
```

Produces the following output:

```
Console was cleared.
========================
0 = Apples
1 = Oranges
3 = Pear

first = function ()
{
  var len = this.length;

  if (len === 0) throw new Error("Array empty");

  return array[0];
}

last = function ()
{
  var len = this.length;
  if (len === 0) throw new Error("Empty array");
  return array[len - 1];
}

========================

first = Apples
last  = Pear

========================

0 = a
1 = b
2 = c

last = function ()
{
  var len = this.length;
  if (len === 0) throw new Error("Empty array");
  return array[len - 1];
}

========================
newArray.first is not a function
last is undefined
```

All of which is fine except for the last line of the output, which says, `"last is undefined."`

Why is the `last` function undefined even though I added it to the `Array` class/constructor's prototype?

Comment: For what it's worth, Mozilla says extending native prototypes is bad practice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain

Comment: @cs01 Thank you. Understandably so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `last` method is added to prototype and executed correctly. There is no problem here.

The problem is that `last` call returns `undefined`, and the error produced is `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` on this line:

```
console.log("last  = " + last.toString());
```

because `last` is undefined. This happens because you use `array` instead of `this` here:

```
last = function ()
{
  var len = this.length;
  if (len === 0) throw new Error("Empty array");
  return this[len - 1];
}
```

And also you need to add `first` method to prototype to avoild `newArray.first is not a function` error.

Comment: Thanks very much. :-)

Comment: Yes, the `first` I intentionally did not add to `newArray` just to see what will happen. I am just trying to mess things up to learn. :-)